# Is it possible to use text-overflow: ellipsis on a button element?

Tags: css

I am not sure whether it is possible to use the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` style on a `<button>` element. Here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/tK727/

Comment: Looks like you’ve discovered a bug in WebKit (the rendering engine used by Chrome and Safari). Please report it at http://new.wkbug.com/ so it can be fixed in a future release.

Comment: There is a bug on Chromium related to this: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107014

Answer (score 67):

Due to limitations in browsers, wrap the button text inside e.g. a `span` element and set the styles on it. Example (available as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hEPZ/) too):

```
<style>
.buttontext {
  width: 95px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}​
</style>
<button><span class=buttontext>Very long text Very long text
Very long text</span></button>
```

Comment: This works. Just a short comment: I would suggest to use a `div` instead of a `span` element, then you can omit `display: block`.

Answer (score 18):

Update 2020:

```css
button {
  width: 95px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<button>Very long text Very long text Very long text</button>
```

Does seems to work on chrome now (tested with chromium 86)

Answer (score -1):

ya its possible & i have tested on major browsers as well as its working

**you can see the live demo:-**http://jsfiddle.net/tK727/2/

[you can read more about text-overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

Comment: Tested in chrome also? You might look at the below answer.

Comment: This does not work in Chrome, the span suggestion works across browsers

Comment: This approach DOES work in Chrome 84 and Firefox 78