# CSS textOverflow: 'ellipsis' not working?

Tags: css, typescript, react-bootstrap

I am working on a project in TSX file where I am using CSS style in the following

```
<Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
        style={{
          bottom: 5,
          width: '100%',
          textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          color: 'red',
          display: 'block',
          whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        }}>
        {accountName}
      </Button>
```

[image]

Here overflow properties are not working while color and other things worked.
This style is applied on **accountName** under the Button tag.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe its `text-overflow` property, could you please try with this.

Comment: @AnshJ it's not text-overflow it's textOverflow I am correct.

Comment: seems ellipsis does not work in button https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905409/is-it-possible-to-use-text-overflow-ellipsis-on-a-button-element

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected for me in Chrome `94.0.4606.81`:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.15.8/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

function Button (props) {
  const {accountName} = props;
  const handleClick = () => console.log('click');
  return (<button
    aria-controls="simple-menu"
    aria-haspopup="true"
    onClick={handleClick}
    style={{
      bottom: 5,
      width: '100%',
      textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      color: 'red',
      display: 'block',
      whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    }}>
    {accountName}
  </button>);
}

const accountName = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`;

ReactDOM.render(<Button {...{accountName}} />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your work but it not working for me when I use width: "100%" it works in 'px' only. I am using a div tag which width is 33.333% of the whole windows now in 33% I have two Image one hamburger icon and a button in one line. now I want to fix this button text. I hope you understand, for more information I have share my UI screenshot.